# How to open String class to rewrite to_s method

Tags: ruby

I want to rewrite the `to_s` method so that I can print the money in `number_to_currency` format. How do I do it? Is there any way to print all `Integer` or `Float` variables in `number_to_currency` format without calling `number_to_currency` method?

I ran this code in the console:

```
require 'pry'
require 'action_view'
include ActionView::Helpers


class String
  def to_s(x)
    number_to_currency(x)
  end
end

sum = 0
0.upto(one_fifth-1) do |line_no|
  sum += lo_to_hi[line_no].last
end
ap("bottom #{one_fifth} sum:#{sum}, average #{sum/one_fifth}")
```

and got this exception: `` in `to_s': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError) ``.

Comment: Be very careful here - this is a wide ranging change (eg do you want JSON serialization to also include currency?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `to_s` should have an argument (because the definition in the parent class (probably`Object`) doesn't.). You can either use `to_s` as it is (no arguments) or create a new method which takes an argument but isn't called `to_s`

In other words, if you want to override a method you have to keep the exact same method signature (that is, its name and the number of arguments it takes).

What if you try:

```
class String
    def to_s_currency(x)
        number_to_currency(x)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the `to_s` method has no argument. And it's dangerous to call other methods in `to_s` when you don't know if that method also calls the `to_s`. (It seems that the `number_to_currency` calls the number's `to_s` indeed) After several attempts, this trick may work for your float and fixnum numbers:

```
class Float
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  alias :old_to_s :to_s
  def to_s
    return old_to_s if caller[0].match(':number_to_rounded')
    number_to_currency(self.old_to_s)
  end
end

class Fixnum
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  alias :old_to_s :to_s
  def to_s
    return old_to_s if caller[0].match(':number_to_rounded')
    number_to_currency(self.old_to_s)
  end
end
```

Note that in this trick, the method uses `match(':number_to_rounded')` to detect the caller and avoid recursive call. If any of your methods has the name like "number_to_rounded" and calls `to_s` on your number, it will also get the original number.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Note that the child class method definitions take precedence over the parent definitions, so overriding Object or Numeric won't work.  Numeric doesn't actually have a `to_s` to start. You need to define it for Float and Fixnum individually.

Answer (score 0):

As, you want to print all `int` and  `float` variables in `number_to_currency`, you have to overwrite `to_s` function in `Fixnum`/`Integer` and `Float` class, something like following:

As pointed out by Stefan, `Integer` and `Float` have a common parent class: `Numeric`, you can just do:

```
class Numeric
  def to_s(x)
    number_to_currency(x)
  end
end
```

Comment: `Integer` and `Float` have a common parent class: [`Numeric`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Numeric.html)

Comment: Hi I got errors `salary_lst.rb:9:in `to_s': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, updated.

at pos: great, what was the exact error??

Comment: @saurabh I got this exception: in `to_s': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError).